# Jquery mobile change page to itself

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a website built with jquery mobile(Single page).

I have something like a wizard: e.g. search -> select -> select -> search -> menu -> search -> search. Basically here are only three pages, but i need to change some of them to itself, like search to search, so it will be in a history and to rise a pageshow event etc...

How can i do it?

```
 $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
```

doesn't work in this case: here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4fbqQ/) to playaround.

Comment: What isn't working that you expect to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `allowSamePageTransition` option as discussed in [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)?

Comment: Is there a global setting for this property?

Comment: Not that I know.  Perhaps going over the jqm code will show where this default behavior is set.

Comment: A quick look at the jqm code shows that this property could be set using `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransitions = true`.  The documentation warns about transitioning from and to the same page, so use this with caution.

Comment: There are no stupid questions... they just seem that way after you know how to do it.