# $.mobile.changePage is not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using $.mobile.changePage to transit on a new page upon clicking on listview element.

This is how I am using it,

```
$('ul').children('li').on('click', function () {
 created_date = $.trim($(this).text());
 $.mobile.changePage( "Image.html", {
  transition: 'slide',
  reverse: 'true'
 });                    
});
```

This is the html page

```
<div data-role="page" id="SavedImage" >
 <div data-role="header">
  <h1></h1>
  <a href="#"></a>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content">
  <img src="Image/InScope.png" alt="" style="height:100%; width:100%;" />
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
 </div>
</div>
```

It transits to `image.html`,When I click on back button it must go to `listview`.But it transits to `listview` page and again come backs to image.html page.

How to prevent it to coming back to `image.html`.

Comment: You have to show more relevant code and markup than that.

Comment: @peterm i have edited my question and added markup and code

Comment: IMHO nothing wrong in posted code. Can you reproduce your problem in jsFiddle?

Comment: looks like there is an extra  } in the code above?

Comment: @Clinton that has happened while editing.. now i removed

Comment: @peterm i havent used jsfiddle. how to use it??.

Comment: @user2143817 http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see rest of your code but I think I understand your problem. If I deduced it correctly your problem is easily solvable and I think you didn't told us everything.

Let me guess, first time it works great but every other time there's a problem you have described.

Change your click binding code to this:

```
$('ul').children('li').off('click').on('click', function () { 
    created_date = $.trim($(this).text());

    $.mobile.changePage( "Image.html", {
                        transition: 'slide',
                        reverse: 'true'
    });
});
```

Basically each time you return to your list page click event will be bind again. With each bind a click on li element will trigger several changePage events that will cause your problem.

Comment: @user2143817 - Yes,you can go for what Gajotres is suggesting.

Comment: @Gajotre thanks for the answer it works. but i have defined `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#SavedImage", function() {
   
    alert("in html");
    var foldername = sessionStorage.getItem('foldername');
    var allignnmae = sessionStorage.getItem('Allignname');
    alert(foldername+"\n"+allignnmae);
    var headerdiv = '<center><div style="color:#fff;"> in '+foldername+' </div>'
    +'<div style="color:#fff;">'+nnmae+'</div></center>';

    $('#savedImageHeader').append(headerdiv);
    });
  
  </script>` in html page. it is not working.

Comment: I have added a id to <div data-role="content" > as id=savedImageHeader. and trying to append append headerdiv to it. previously it was displaying

Comment: Can you please update your question with this new problem? It will be much more readable. And don't worry I will still be here to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an error in your code, this might be a bug of some unexpected behaviour of a browser. Things to consider:
I have faced similar issues but i have done below things.You can try this.

- try removing `href="#"` from the link
- put `false` in reverse value.
- Instead of using `changePage()` apply directly `href="Image.html"` `data-transition="slide"`
- In the `click` and `return false`.

If Any of above doesn't work then go to this question.It's same question what you have asked.

[jquery-mobile-change-page-to-itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410553/jquery-mobile-change-page-to-itself)

Comment: i will check the link. but if i use window.open instead of $.mobile.changePage it works fine..

Comment: @user2143817-If you use window.open then your whole page will be reloaded.So,page will be loaded slowly.But,when you use changePage() it will change the page very fast due to Ajax request.If you fill fine with the window.open then go ahead with it.

Comment: for mobile device window.open doesn't looks good. so having concern to use it.

Comment: @user2143817-Yes.it doesn't look goot at all.You will not feel your application as a mobile application.So,try to resolve issue for changePage(). window.open will dramatically reduce the performance of your application.